# Find in Perl a jpg with the smallest width and height

Tags: linux, windows, perl

I am looking for a way to find (1) a  file with the smallest width and with (2) the smallest height and show these numbers (preferably command line, either Linux or Windows). I have no idea what tool to use but I think that Perl with one of its packages has probably this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full Perl program that does as you ask. You may have to install [`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Magick) as it isn't a core module. As it stands, the program checks all files ending `.jpg` in the current working directory. You may want to change the call to `glob` to check files in a different directory or with a different file type.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Magick;

my %data;
for my $jpg (glob '*.jpg') {
    my $magick = Image::Magick->new;
    $magick->Read($jpg);
    $data{$jpg} = { map { $_ => $magick->Get($_) } qw/ width height / };
} 

my ($least_width,  $least_width_file);
my ($least_height, $least_height_file);

while (my ($jpg, $info) = each %data) {

    unless ($least_width and $least_width <= $info->{width}) {
      ($least_width_file, $least_width) = ($jpg, $info->{width});
    }

    unless ($least_height and $least_height <= $info->{height}) {
      ($least_height_file, $least_height) = ($jpg, $info->{height});
    }
}

print "\n";
printf "File with least width (%d) is %s\n", $least_width, $least_width_file; 
printf "File with least height (%d) is %s\n", $least_height, $least_height_file;
```

---

**Update**

To follow @nwellnhof's suggestion and use [`Image::Size`](https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Size) instead of [`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Magick), you should replace the `use` statement and the `for` loop with the following code.

```
use Image::Size qw/ imgsize /;

my %data;
for my $jpg (glob '*.jpg') {
    @{ $data{$jpg} }{qw/ width height /} = imgsize($jpg);
}
```

---

**Update**

This version adds some statistical information to the output as requested. It uses the [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy) module to more concisely find the smallest files. This isn't a core module and is likely to need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Size qw/ imgsize /;
use List::UtilsBy qw/ min_by /;

my %data;
for my $jpg (glob '*.jpg') {
    @{ $data{$jpg} }{qw/ width height /} = imgsize($jpg);
} 

my @least_width_files  = min_by { $data{$_}{width} }  keys %data;
my $least_width = $data{$least_width_files[0]}{width};

my @least_height_files = min_by { $data{$_}{height} } keys %data;
my $least_height = $data{$least_height_files[0]}{height};

print "\n";
if (@least_width_files == keys %data) {
    printf "All files have a width of %d\n", $least_width;
}
else {
    my $n = @least_width_files;
    printf "%d file%s %s the least width of %d:\n", $n, $n == 1 ? ('', 'has') : ('s', 'have'), $least_width;
    print "    $_\n" for @least_width_files;
}

print "\n";
if (@least_height_files == keys %data) {
    printf "All files have a height of %d\n", $least_height;
}
else {
    my $n = @least_height_files;
    printf "%d file%s %s the least height of %d:\n", $n, $n == 1 ? ('', 'has') : ('s', 'have'), $least_height;
    print "    $_\n" for @least_height_files;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will check it tomorrow on Windows and Linux and tell about results.

Comment: I found [`Image::Size`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Size) to be an excellent and more light-weight module if you're only concerned with image sizes.

Comment: @nwellnhof: I think you should write that up as a solution

Comment: @Borodin Would it be possible that you could rewrite your code to use  Image::Size? I find it very hand to rewrite it on my own because your code and nwekknhof's are quite different from each other.

Comment: @Borodin You're genius! The code works great. You have saved a lost of my time! I do not want to be greedy, but if a piece of code stating that all files have the size width and heigh could be added, I could not have been happier. If you think that is too much, it won't of course change anything. You have been extremely helpful.

Comment: @menteith:  What, you mean if *all* files in the directory have the same dimensions? Or do you want a list of all files that have the same width and height as the smallest ones? I also think `@nwellnhof` should get the upvote, as all I have done is to implement his suggestion.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing if all files in a directory have the same width and height as well as if there is a file (or files) with the smallest width and/or height. The latter means that if all files do not have the same dimensions, I would like to know what file(s) has the smallest width and/or height. Have I been more clear now? Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to upvote an answer.

Comment: @menteith: Okay I've added another update. However I would rather you had tried to achieve it yourself, as your questions to Stack Overflow will never end unless you try to learn the language yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I would just use ImageMagick from the command line.  You might need to install it first (with e.g. `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` on Ubuntu):

```
narrowest=$(identify *jpg | sort -nr -k3 | tail -n 1 | cut -d\[ -f1)
shortest=$(identify *jpg | sort -tx -nr -k2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d\[ -f1)
```

On Windows, that's not an option unless you install Cygwin or something.

On both Linux and Windows, you can use the `Image::Magick` module to access that functionality from Perl, but you'll have to install the module yourself.  See Borodin's answer for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the module [`Image::Size`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Size) for that task. Compared to full-fledged image manipulation libraries like `Image::Magick`, it doesn't decompress and read a whole image into memory just to get its size. So it should be much faster and less memory-hungry, especially for large images.

Something along the following lines should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Size;

my ($min_width, $min_height);

for my $filename (glob '*.jpg') {
    my ($width, $height) = imgsize($filename);
    $min_width  = $width  if !defined($min_width)  || $width < $min_width;
    $min_height = $height if !defined($min_height) || $height < $min_height;
}

if (defined($min_width) && defined($min_height)) {
    print "Minimum width: $min_width\n";
    print "Minimum height: $min_height\n";
}
else {
    print "No images found\n";
}
```

Comment: Works great! I have encountered problems installing Image::Magick on Windows. Your solution is very quick and does the job. Much appreciated!

Comment: I would also appreciate if you could add two twings. Firstly, the script could show the name of the files (smallest width and highth). Secondly, information that all files have the same width and height (if it is the case) would be also very nice.

Comment: @menteith StackOverflow isn't a site where other people solve all your problems for free. The answers to your question should provide you with enough details to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. Since your answer fails to give all the things I have asked for in my first post I cannot accept your answer.